# Javascript - using document.onkeyup to splice an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm in the process of building a hangman game.  I'm attempting to capture a user guess with document.onkeyup and then splice that item from an array. If the user made the right guess, that is.  Here is my function:

```js
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var i = alphabet.indexOf;

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  console.log("event=", event);
  var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();

  if (userGuess === alphabet[1] || alphabet[2] || alphabet[3]) {

    alphabet.splice(i, 1 || 2 || 3);
    console.log(alphabet);
  }
};
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to add many more lines of code to achieve same desired effect, as I know how to splice and push, just can't seem to figure out if this is possible?
I've been googling for quite some time and only seem to find answers to much more complex issues.  I know this is an elementary issue, but I could really use the help - please and thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If user clicks some button on keyboard, e.g. `a` and the *word* includes `a` letter, splice it out from the `alphabet` array?

Comment: precisely - I'm in the process of pseudocoding, hence the small chunk of the bigger function

Comment: Still didn't answer my question...

Comment: yes, i will have an array of many words, and another array of the alphabet - would like to use document.onkeyup to capture user guess, compare it to word from an array, and if the userChoice(a letter) is in the word in question, then splice the letter from the alphabet

Comment: This question makes no sense. `1 || 2 || 3` is not a useful operation in JS (serious question, what do you think does this do?). The use of the word "splice" is unclear. How would splicing an array help in a hangman game? Why is there an array with the letters a-z in the first place? Isn't a hangman game where the users guesses missing letters in a word? Wouldn't it make more sense to compare the entered letter with the word you are seeking instead of an a-z list?

Comment: @tomalak, thanks for the input but my directions explicitly state that user can only guess a specific letter once(to avoid losing multiple lives for the same keystroke) therefore, yes, I must splice the alphabet array. or so my thinking goes.  I'm only 40days into coding, excuse my newness. I'm a dedicated learner nonetheless.  also the || was an experiment, trying to see if whole word could be compared at once)

Comment: I would simply collect the key codes the user has already pressed into an empty array and prevent pressing a key twice by checking whether a key code already exists in the array (use indexOf for that). You can create a bounds check (a-z) by checking the character code (a = 97, z = 122).

Comment: I see where you are coming from with `1 || 2 || 3` but that's not how things work. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following solution. If user hits the button and the given word includes that specified character, remove it from the `alphabet` array. Feel free to modify it as you wish.

```js
var words = "One apple a day",
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) { //listen to the keyboard events
  if (e.keyCode > 64 && e.keyCode < 91 && alphabet.indexOf(e.key) > -1) { //to avoid spam with logs, we will restrict the range of keycodes from 64 to 91 (a-z) ===> a keycode is 65, z is 90 
    if (words.indexOf(e.key) > -1) { //if clicked letter is included inside the words
      alphabet.splice(alphabet.indexOf(e.key), 1); //then remove it from the alphabet
      console.log('correct letter');
    } else {
      console.log('incorrect letter');
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabet)); //show the alphabet and its actual state
  }
});
```

Comment: wow, thanks - now if you don't mind giving me a brief explanation as to what is going on, as I really don't come here to only get the solution; I'm more of a why-is-this-the-solution kinda guy.  I appreciate your time either way!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you - one day when I'm where you're at, I'll chip in with the newbies too. Thanks for the help, again.

Comment: The filter for "event spam" is pointless. The event has already occurred and called the listener, so it doesn't stop anything. It just introduces 3 additional tests that would be filtered by the next test anyway.

Comment: @RobG I think you might missed my point or maybe I've just written it not really accurately, I just meant that we will avoid spam in the console and we will listen - we will operate only on 65-90 keycode events. I will change it.

Comment: @Kinduser—it might be better to just test against the remaining alphabet and just report that either the character is not a letter (`/[a-z]/.test(event.key)`) or has already been used (passes the letter test but fails when tested against the remaining alphabet characters) .

Comment: @RobG Are you sure that regex may be better solution than operators?

Comment: I'd go straight to the `words.indexOf` test and if it fails, just say "Incorrect guess". I was just suggesting the other test if there is also a need to report whether the character is a valid letter or guess, and whether it's been guessed already which might be seen as more user friendly (which I think was the point of your "spam filter"). ;-)

Comment: @RobG Honestly speaking, maybe it's just too late and I'm too tired for this, but I just don't really get your point. However feel free to edit my post if you wish. Have a good night my dear bro (: